# Does closing a BufferedOutputStream also close the underlying OutputStream?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am streaming binary data (a CSV file extracted from the database as a Clob) to the browser by calling response.getOutputStream() and would normally wrap the OutputStream in a BufferedOutputStream when copying the data.

Should I close the BufferedOutputStream or will this also close the underlying OutputStream?

[Extra question: Do I need to use a BufferedOutputStream in this case or is the response already buffered?]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it closes it. As for whether you should close it - are you expecting to write anything else to the response stream? If not, I think it's fine to close it. If you don't close it, you should obviously flush it instead - but I suspect you could figure that bit out for yourself :)

The behaviour is actually inherited from `FilterOutputStream`. The Javadocs for for `FilterOutputStream.close` state:

> The close method of `FilterOutputStream`
>   calls its flush method, and then calls
>   the close method of its underlying
>   output stream.

As for whether you should buffer it - I'm not sure that this is well defined. It may be buried in the servlet spec somewhere - and it may even be configurable (sometimes you really don't want buffering, but if you can buffer the whole response it means you can serve a nicer error page if things go wrong after you've started writing).

Answer (score 5):

Closing the BufferedOutputStream will also close the underlying OutputStream. You *should* close the BufferedOutputStream so that it flushes its contents before closing the underlying stream. See the implementation of FilterOutputStream.close() (from which BufferedOutputStream extends) to convince yourself.

I guess that whether or not the response stream given to your servlet is buffered or not depends on the implementation of your Servlet Container. FWIW I know that Tomcat does buffer its servlet response streams by default, in order to attempt to set the content-length HTTP header.