# Files written with FileWriter are either 32 KB, 24 KB, 16 KB, ... big or empty

Tags: java, file-io

I read a file into a string, change the first line and then write this string into a new file. I do this through the following code (a little bit shortened):

```
while(jspIterator.hasNext()){
                    String line = (String) jspIterator.next();
                    if (i == 0) {
                        if (line.startsWith("bla bla") && line.endsWith("yada")) {
                            line = line.replaceFirst("this", "that");
                        }
                    }
                    jspAsString += line;
                    i++;
                }

FileWriter newJspWriter = new FileWriter(newJspFile);
                newJspWriter.write(jspAsString);
```

Now the files written this way are either 32, 24, 16, 8 KByte big or completely empty. When debugging I see that the String is assembled correctly. When I print the variable jspAsString to the console it also appears correct.

Do you know why FileWriter behaves this way?

Comment: Are you closing your FileWriter?

Comment: Sounds like you are not properly calling `flush()` or `close()` on the writer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely you did not `close()` the `FileWriter`.

#### Related questions

- [Closing Streams in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515975/closing-streams-in-java)
- [Closing a Java FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156508/closing-a-java-fileinputstream)
- [Does close ever throw an IOException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588546/does-close-ever-throw-an-ioexception)
- [Does closing a BufferedOutputStream also close the underlying OutputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428118/does-closing-a-bufferedoutputstream-also-close-the-underlying-outputstream)